# Google AppEngine Server wont start on netbeans 7.4

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans-7.4

I just downloaded the Google AppEngine java sdk and netbeans plugins. Installation was smooth until i tried to run the example app. The server wont start. I get the notification on bottom right : 'guestbook run' or 'Starting Server Google AppEngine' but nothing happens after that it just keeps on loading forever. No exceptions or anything. I'm using Netbeans 7.4. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all consider posting `server logs`.In your case I believe you are trying to start it for first time.In your guest book project: simply put:

`<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>`

in your war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application></application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

After running your app browse to `localhost:8080`(or any other port in your case).You should see a guestbook page asking to sign in.
See answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780732/unable-to-deploy-the-application-on-google-app-engine-appengine-web-xml-does-n).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've actually had better luck with Eclipse  and the Google Plugin for Eclipse since posting this question. I was able to deploy it to app engine without any problems.

Comment: I tried this with Netbeans 7.4 as mentioned in your title. And I had to make these changes to make things work :)

Comment: Cheers! It works. I guess I was wrong to assume that the sample app would be configured properly.